# Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error***

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I tried to import tensorflow in pycharm and I got this:

> C:\Users\Public\anaconda\anaconda3\envs\tensor\pythonw.exe "C:/Users/Muhammed Jaabir/PycharmProjects/untitled6/tensor.py"
>   C:\Users\Public\anaconda\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\h5py__init__.py:40: UserWarning: h5py is running against HDF5 1.10.5 when it was built against 1.10.4, this may cause problems
>     '{0}.{1}.{2}'.format(*version.hdf5_built_version_tuple)
>   Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error***
>   The HDF5 header files used to compile this application do not match
>   the version used by the HDF5 library to which this application is linked.
>   Data corruption or segmentation faults may occur if the application continues.
>   This can happen when an application was compiled by one version of HDF5 but
>   linked with a different version of static or shared HDF5 library.
>   You should recompile the application or check your shared library related
>   settings such as 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'.
>   You can, at your own risk, disable this warning by setting the environment
>   variable 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'.
>   Setting it to 2 or higher will suppress the warning messages totally.
>   Headers are 1.10.4, library is 1.10.5
>           SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION
>           =================================

### General Information:

```
               HDF5 Version: 1.10.5
              Configured on: 2019-03-04
              Configured by: Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64
                Host system: Windows-10.0.17763
          Uname information: Windows
                   Byte sex: little-endian
         Installation point: C:/Program Files/HDF5
```

### Compiling Options:

```
                 Build Mode: 
          Debugging Symbols: 
                    Asserts: 
                  Profiling: 
         Optimization Level:
```

### Linking Options:

```
                      Libraries: 
  Statically Linked Executables: OFF
                        LDFLAGS: /machine:x64
                     H5_LDFLAGS: 
                     AM_LDFLAGS: 
                Extra libraries: 
                       Archiver: 
                         Ranlib:
```

### Languages:

```
                          C: yes
                 C Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe 19.16.27027.1
                   CPPFLAGS: 
                H5_CPPFLAGS: 
                AM_CPPFLAGS: 
                     CFLAGS:  /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3
                  H5_CFLAGS: 
                  AM_CFLAGS: 
           Shared C Library: YES
           Static C Library: YES

                    Fortran: OFF
           Fortran Compiler:  
              Fortran Flags: 
           H5 Fortran Flags: 
           AM Fortran Flags: 
     Shared Fortran Library: YES
     Static Fortran Library: YES

                        C++: ON
               C++ Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe 19.16.27027.1
                  C++ Flags: /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc
               H5 C++ Flags: 
               AM C++ Flags: 
         Shared C++ Library: YES
         Static C++ Library: YES

                        JAVA: OFF
               JAVA Compiler:
```

### Features:

```
                   Parallel HDF5: OFF
Parallel Filtered Dataset Writes: 
              Large Parallel I/O: 
              High-level library: ON
                    Threadsafety: OFF
             Default API mapping: v110
  With deprecated public symbols: ON
          I/O filters (external):  DEFLATE DECODE ENCODE
                             MPE: 
                      Direct VFD: 
                         dmalloc: 
  Packages w/ extra debug output: 
                     API Tracing: OFF
            Using memory checker: OFF
 Memory allocation sanity checks: OFF
          Function Stack Tracing: OFF
       Strict File Format Checks: OFF
    Optimization Instrumentation: 
Bye...
```

Comment: what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please can you install `h5py` as below

```
  pip install h5py --upgrade --no-dependencies --force
```